# Do questions with LaTeX in titles appear in Hot Questions?

Tags: support, mathjax, titles, hot-questions-list

I haven't seen any questions in Hot Questions (HQ) with LaTeX in titles.

Maybe there aren't many popular questions with LaTeX in titles or maybe I never thought about it when I saw LaTeX in HQ. Or maybe questions with LaTeX in titles are less likely to appear in HQ?

Comment: Marginally related older discussion from this meta: [Title formatting of LaTeX in StackExchange hot questions list](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10570/title-formatting-of-latex-in-stackexchange-hot-questions-list)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Questions from math.SE that contain LaTeX markup are excluded from the list of hot network questions; see [this meta.SE thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237475/are-the-questions-with-tex-markup-in-titles-excluded-from-hot-network-questions).

On the other hand, questions from other sites that contain `$` signs in them are still picked up, and when they show up on math.SE mathjax processes them, which often gives horrible results; see [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229363/exclude-tex-se-question-titles-from-mathjax-parsing-in-hot-network-questions) for example. (I don't believe this has been fixed yet, I've seen the issue recently.)